# Expected number of rolls needed to get four distinct results

Tags: probability, dice, coupon-collector

> Suppose I have a fair, six-sided die. What is the expected number of rolls it would take me to get four distinct outcomes?

Answer (score 1):

Use Geometric probability, this is called Coupon Collector's problem.

Mean number of rolls until the first: $\mathbf{E}X_1 = 1$

Mean number of rolls until the second: $\mathbf{E}X_2 = \frac{1}{\frac{5}{6}} = \frac{6}{5}$

Can you handle from here?

Comment: What about if I wanted to do 75% of the faces on an N sided dice? How would I do that? I'm assuming the answer is a function